# Thermochemistry of gabapentin

Tags: pharmacology, pharmacodynamics, pharmacokinetics

So I am taking a new class at my institution called Theoretic Nuclear Thermochemical Pharmacology, (I know big name, it's an elective from a real pioneering fronteirsman in our department :P) and I am curious about the metabolism of gabapentin and how this might relate to thermochemistry?  I am curious how this drug metabolizes in the liver and how it neurochemically alters the brain such that it reduces mania in patients that are bipolar and may also have mood disorders.  Any kind of relevant literature would be appreciated, something to guide me in the right direction.  I mean I understand liver metabolism and what it does but its relation to mania and how it's thermochemical still boggles me.

Comment: @ChrisStronks Isn't this a [commonly accepted term](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thermochemical)? Anyhow, I think in some cases entropy dominates rather than heat.

Comment: Also, the way you phrased your question is too open ended, and it's hard to answer. You should rewrite it so that it has one clear answer.

Comment: @Superbest - thanks for the link. Having read this weblink, and re-reading the question I think I would have phrased the question as ***"I am wondering (1) what the drug metabolism is of gabapentin in the liver; (2) whether these catabolic liver reaction(s) are exothermic or endothermic; (3) how gabapentin or its metabolites reduce mania in bipolar patients (i.e., gabapentin's pharmacodynamics); and (4) how the thermochemistry of liver-catabolism of gabapentin relates to its manialytic properties"*** I think the question's scope is too broad, as it mixes basic toxicology and neuropharmacology.